# Find the Perimeter of a rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The sides of a rectangle are (3x+2)ft and (4x-3)ft . Find the perimeter of the rectangle
I tried adding them up came to 14 to the 4th -2 am I right?

Comment: Please show us your calculation in detail

Comment: well 3+4 =7 4 sides + 4 x's is 14 to the fourth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Perimeter of a Rectangle $=2l+2w \therefore P = 2(3x+2) + 2(4x-3) =(6x+4) + (8x-6) = 14x-2$

Comment: would't that be 14x -2? and lucian gave me different answer

Comment: Our answer's are the same as $2l+2w \equiv 2(l+w)$. See, worked out the result would be the same.

Comment: 2*3x =6x 2*2 =4 + 2*4x = 8x 2*-3 =-6 all equals 14x-2

Comment: Whoops, I didnt remember the minus side.

Answer (score 1):

Perimeter is $$2[(3x+2)+(4x-3)]=2(7x-1)=14x-2.$$

Comment: Lucian, $2-3=-1$..

Comment: Corrected the error